How can I find out which shortcut is using a particular key combination?
I'm going crazy here... I'm using Divvy and it seems over time macOS is changing some default keyboard shortcuts in the system. Because on an older running installation, I could easily use the combination Opt+← and Opt+→ but I can not on a newer MacBook.
It simply tells me that this shortcut is already used by a system-wide shortcut. Great.
The thing is that when I go through Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts I don't actually see this combination set anywhere. Also when I use it nothing happens on my system. Great.
Questions:

How do I find out which system shortcut is using this combination?
How do I disable this unknown shortcut to free up my beloved key combination?


There is Apple support page Mac Keyboard Shortcuts. According to that these shortcuts are for moving the insertion point to the beginning or end of the current line. Therefore nothing happens if no insertion point active.

ah yea nice... and maybe any way to change/disable this so I can reuse that shortcut?

Nit picking,  ⌘← and ⌘→ are for beginning and end of line. ⌥← and ⌥→ are for beginning and end of words.

@SteveM - yes, mea culpa. I don't know why I thought it was Command

Here are two apps which show the keyboard shortcuts for the system and current active application:
KeyCue (paid): https://ergonis.com/keycue
KeyClu (free): https://github.com/Anze/KeyCluCask/
They do not show all keyboard shortcuts across all apps, but could get you started to find why a shortcut is not working in the app you are using.
The KeyCue website also has this bit, although I've not tried it:

KeyCue allows you to define own shortcuts and overwrite existing ones directly in the menubar. Assign or change shortcuts to your commonly used commands and get more efficient in everyday life with your customized shortcuts.

Of course, this is of no help if for your use case if the action you want to perform is not on a menu (I do not use Divvy so I do not know).
